# Trigger an action whenever a mail is received using Java Spring-boot JavaMail

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am using spring-boot to send notification emails to users. SMTP properties like username, host and password are customizable and I am storing it in a properties file. I want to trigger an action whenever a user replies to these emails. Is there a way I can do this?

Currently I am having a scheduled a quartz job which keeps checking if any new emails are there in every minute. It looks like an overload. Is there a better way ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.